# Unable to open .dat file created by textedit using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am going through the following part of the Matlab tutorial.

[image]

And I followed the instruction to create a magik.dat file using textEdit by saving it as a normal file first and then changed its name to "magik.dat." When I entered the statement "load magick.dat," it gave me the following:

> > > load magik.dat
> > >       Error using load
> > >       Number of columns on line 2 of ASCII file
> > >       /Users/name/Documents/MATLAB/magik.dat
> > >       must be the same as previous lines.

And when I opened my magik.dat file using Xcode, it shows the following:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1187\cocoasubrtf390
>   {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
>   {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
>   \margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
>   \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural
>   \f0\fs24 \cf0 16.0 3.0 2.0 13.0
>   \
>   5.0 10.0 11.0 8.0
>   \
>   9.0 6.0 7.0 12.0
>   \
>   4.0 15.0 14.0 1.0}

I couldn't figure what exactly Matlab means by the second line has to be the same as the previous one. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like when you saved it in textEdit, you saved as a file format other than "plain text"... when you saved it the first time, before changing the extension, what was the extension?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have saved the file in the `.rtf` format from textEdit. You should input the data in Xcode and either save it from there as `.dat` or as `.txt` and change the extension to `.dat` afterwards.

To more directly answer your question, MATLAB expects each row of an input file to have the same number of columns (when you use the load function anyways). When MATLAB opened your file, it found all the garbage that tells other programs that this is an `.rtf` formatted file. MATLAB doesn't know about this, so it just tried to read what had been put in the file, and found that the number of columns in the second row didn't match the number of columns in the first row. That's when MATLAB gave up and told you to find the problem :-)